# Aligning image with text

Tags: html, css

I've aligned the blond guy's picture on the left with the text on the right.

But I can't get the girl with the x-ray to align with text on the right (it's currently below her).

How do you do this?

http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/clinica/corpo-clinico/

```
<p style="float: left;">IMAGE OF BLOND GUY</p>

<p style="float: right;">HIS QUALIFICATIONS</p>


<p style="float: left;">IMAGE OF X-RAY GIRL</p>

<p style="float: right;">HER QUALIFICATIONS</p>
```

Comment: Please don't make us resort to <View Page Source>. In other words, could you post the mark-up you're using?

Comment: Point taken. Edited the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5LqUB/

Here's the your code, modified:

```
<p style="float: left;">THE IMAGE</p>

<p style="float: right;">HIS QUALIFICATIONS</p>

<p style="clear:both ; float: left;">THE IMAGE</p>

<p style="float: right;">HER QUALIFICATIONS</p>​
```

See how I added `clear:both` to the third `<p></p>`? That forces it down to the next line and then floats the fourth `<p></p>` beside it.

I also added `margin-bottom:20px` to my image in the first paragraph just to put some space between the first and second rows.

It would be cleaner markup, though, to create CSS classes in an external stylesheet, like this:

```
.clear { clear:both }
.left { float:left }
.right { float:right }
```

and then have your HTML look like this:

```
<p class="left">THE IMAGE</p>

<p class="right">HIS QUALIFICATIONS</p>

<p class="clear left">THE IMAGE</p>

<p class="right">HER QUALIFICATIONS</p>​
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Couldn't get it to work Cynthia: http://www.joaoalexandre.com/wordpressteste/clinica/corpo-clinico/

Comment: That is because your actual code on your site is not at all like the code you gave as an example.

Comment: I added your code to CSS and to the markup. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Wait, you did it. I placed attachment_498 alignleft (like #497 was) and your code worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the structure a little bit if that may please you

```
<style>
  .container{
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    min-height:400px;
  }

  .photo{
    float:left;
  }
</style>

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="photo">guy</div>
  <div class="text">guy_text</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">gal</div>
  <div class="text">gal_text</div>
</div>
```

---

This will work too:

```
<style>
  .container{
    display:block;
    height:400px;
    min-height:400px;
  }

  .photo{
    float:left;
  }

  .text {
    margin-left:10px;
  }
</style>

<img class="photo" src="guy"/>
<div class="text"><p>guy_text</p></div>
```

Comment: If I edit the CSS would other pages change as well?

I only need this pic on the left qualifications on the right for this page.

Comment: are you using the same css for another page?

Comment: My CSS file is for the whole wordpress installation.

I don't have any specific CSS for this page.

I'm just editing the markup as I go and as required for each page.

Was this what you asked?

Comment: If you want greater control, you can specify classes like "guyphoto" and "galphoto" (in addition to "photo") in order to differentiate

Comment: So create a guyphoto class and galphoto class in the CSS?

Using Nina's code?

Comment: in that case you can add a specific class to say the div with galphoto and make specific changes to it, in case you have less time and cannot afford to rewrite

Comment: So I would repeat 2 blocks of one of the two codes you posted?

like:

.container-for-guy
rest of code here

.container-for-girl

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing...

I agree with Nina here. I would definitely revise your mark-up to incorporate  and control with CSS, rather than inline style.

Answer (score 0):

By giving a fixed width of `298px` to the containing div You are forcing the `<p>` element after the `img` to drop under it, because block elements (like p and div) behave this way.
first, remove the `width` property and value from this div:

```
<div style="width: 289px" class="wp-caption aligncenter" id="attachment_498"><a href="http://pt.drpedrocoelho.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/dalilacosta.jpg"><img width="279" height="400" class="size-full wp-image-498" title="dalilacosta" alt="Dr.ª Dalila Costa" src="http://pt.drpedrocoelho.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/dalilacosta.jpg"></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Dr.ª Dalila Costa &ndash; Dental House Oeiras</p></div>
```

next, wrap your first `img` and the `p`'s next to it in a separate div.
After this, you should add the next img in a similar way, so you will have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="floatLeft" src="p1.jpg" />
   <p>some text here</p>
   <p>some text here</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img class="floatLeft" src="p2.jpg" />
   <p>some text here</p>
   <p>some text here</p>
</div>


<style>
/* ClearFix */
.container:after { content:"."; line-height:0; visibility:hidden; clear:both; height:0; display:block; }

.container p { float:left; } 
.floatLeft { float:left; }
</style>
```

This is just an example, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Shahar.